# CSS select text which doesn't belong to any tag

Tags: html, css, safari

Sample code

```html
<style>
  #parent-div {
    visibility: hidden
  }
  
  #inner-div {
    visibility: visible
  }
</style>
<div id="parent-div">
  NEED TO HIDE
  <div id="inner-div">
    NEED TO SHOW
  </div>
</div>
```

**Precondition:** I can only edit `css`

**Request:** "NEED TO HIDE" should be hidden and "NEED TO SHOW" should be showed.

**Problem:** The code above works on PC browsers (`Chrome`, `Firefox`,...) but not work on `iPhone`'s browsers (`safari`, `Chrome`) - I tested on `iPhone` 5 and 6.

**My question:**

1. How to fix above issue?
2. How to select "NEED TO HIDE" only? i.e: I want to change it's color, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: exactly like you did --> make sure you don't have any cache on your phone as it should work

Comment: Visit this page with your iPhone and run the snippet. It works fine.